# Enabling PWM sysfs entry

Tags: linux, mips, dts, pwm

I am trying to enable pwm under /sys/class/pwm/. What I am anticipating under this is something like pwmchip0/export etc. I have gone through the following things:

1. Checked that PWM_SYSFS is =y in the config.
2. The dtsi file has the right entries for the pwm.
3. The driver for pwm is being compiled properly.

But when I run build on the target I can see only /sys/class/pwm but nothing underneath.

I have not touched the dts file at all.

If anyone can point me towards the right direction or point out list of things to check for starter I would be grateful.

Please ask if I have missed anything to mention in the question.

Comment: Could you provide dts file you are using and KConfig. Probably pwm devices disabled somehow (in the dts or  kconfig). Check boot log for pwm driver messages.

Comment: Hi Alexander Thanks for the reply. Yes that's correct, in my dtsi file the pwm like all other devices was set as default. Something like this: 

pwm: pwm@f015c000 {
  compatible = "img,xyz-pwm";
  reg = <0xf015c000 0x200>;
  img,cr-periph = <&cr_perip>;
  status = "disabled";
Which had to be enabled from the dts file as below:

&pwm {
       status = "okay";
};

After this point the pwm probe function started getting called by the kernel. The probe function is the one which exports the device through the sysfs. After the changes I can now see /sys/class/pwm/pwmchip0 and so on.

Comment: @VivekB I'm having a similar issue with nothing below /sys/class/pwm. Can you elaborate more (or provide a link) to your solution? There's no reference to /pwm/i in any of the boot/* text files, and no dts(i) files on the entire / tree.

Answer (score 2):

This was actually simple. The reason the PWM entry was missing is because of the fact that the driver probe was not being called at all which means the kernel had no idea there exits a PWM driver. This I noticed from the kernel logs and extra printks in the driver code.

The reason the PWM driver probe was not being called by the kernel is that the device was not enabled in the dtsi file:

```
pwm: pwm@xxxxxxxx {
                compatible = "aaa,bbb-pwm";
                reg = <0xxxxxxxxx 0x200>;
                status = "disabled";
        };
```

To enable it I had to modify (add an entry for PWM) the .dts file:

```
&pwm {
        status = "okay";
};
```

In my case the driver was already written, so I could see the PWM entry immediately after this point. If you are writing a new driver you might have to create all the necessary sysfs entries as required.